# Is there a terminal based "Running out of Disk Space" reset?

Tags: terminal, memory

I often get the notification that I'm

> Running out of Disk Space

I'm usually around ~5gb when the message comes up.  I've found that if I ignore it for a while, it'll continue going down (even while I'm not downloading anything).

Somewhere around ~2gb is when I usually reset my computer, and when it reboots it'll be back up to ~15gb.

It seems pretty clear to me that this is a virtual ram, and/or caching thing.  It's likely from either my browser or the compiler that tends to be running in my terminal.

---

What I want to know is if there's a way to get the effect of resetting my computer without having to reset the entire thing?

I think what I might be looking for is something that stops and closes every application, resets vram, then opens up everything again.  Basically the entire reboot process minus the OS.

If it could do it for all users, that would be even better.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I really want to advise you strongly to consider freeing up space or moving to a larger drive. Almost-full drives suffer from high fragmentation, which not only slows down your system (due to additional B-tree lookups) but also consumes extra space (due to additional B-tree extents entries) and, most pressingly, dramatically increases your chances for filesystem corruption for several distinct reasons. There is a specific reason that macOS is so adamant about reminding you about low free space: You are endangering your data.

Comment: I have 15 gigs of free space (which is the suggested amount), and from what I can tell it would fill up 100gb if given enough time.  Also, I have back-ups of my media and code.